# Unable to set an icon in a listview

Tags: android

I'm new to android programming. I created a ListView and tried setting an icon for each list item using simple adapter. I'm not familiar with viewbinder, so i tried calling super.setImageView and super.setTextView methods from the getview method in the adapter class, but only the icons get displayed not the text.

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/folder_label"
            style="@style/textViewStyle"
            android:id="@+id/textView" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"></TextView>
         <ImageView android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
         <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            style="@style/listViewStyle"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/listView" 
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"`
```

This is my Activity class

```
ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    TextView iView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    optionsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.optionsArray);

    msgMenu = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> msgOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        msgOptionsMap.put(optionsArray[i], (Integer) mThumbIds[i]);

    }
    msgMenu.add(msgOptionsMap);

    lView.setAdapter(new OptionsAdapter(context, msgMenu,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, optionsArray, mThumbIds));
```

The getView method inside the adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(context);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        if (convertView == null) {
            // view.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
            super.setViewImage(view, mThumbIds[position]);
            super.setViewText(tv, msgOptions[position]);
```

Comment: Go through all these [`ListView Tutorials`](http://www.technotalkative.com/category/android/listview/) PS: Start from bottom to top.

Comment: and what if convertView is not null?

Answer (score 0):

You are using this layour in the listView:  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

This layour is defined by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

SO, you have to use in your getview:

```
TextView tv = (textView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
```

instead of:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
```

You should defintely start with simple stuff, here is an excellent tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html